# Using Layouts setRoot() in standalone \Zend\View

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, zend-view

## What I need

I needed a templating engine for a small site and I decided to try using `\Zend\View`. I'm not using Zend Framework itself though.

So basically I want to do some data processing in my custom scripts outside of Zend, and then pass the variables into `\Zend\View` and make it render my templates.

## What I've tried

I was referring to the following manual: [zend.view.quick-start.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html). The basic implementation (where I use `\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer` and `\Zend\View\Model\ViewModel` only) works as expected. But I run into errors when I try something more complex, such as using a common layout.

If I got this right, the `\Zend\View\Model\ViewModel`s can be nested, and I can call the child ones using the predefined placeholders ([zend.view.quick-start.html#nesting-view-models](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#nesting-view-models)). But there should be one primary `ViewModel` that will serve as a Root ([zend.view.quick-start.html#dealing-with-layouts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#dealing-with-layouts)), it will contain the skeleton HTML page with the Doctype and whatever I pass into `headTitle()`, `headMeta()` etc.

I tried to create a viewModel, point it to my root layout using `setTemplate()` and then pass it to the `setRoot()` function, but it didn't work. I tried to search the code for that function , and I found it in the /Zend/View/Helper/ViewModel.php. It takes an instance of `Zend\View\Model\ModelInterface` and not an instance of `\Zend\View\Model\ViewModel`. But when I try to create a new ModelInterface and setTemplate to it, it throws me

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Zend\View\Model\ModelInterface

It becomes overcomplicated, and I can't figure this out.

### Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/zend/autoloader.php';

$resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack();
$resolver->addPath('/path/to/views/');

$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('layout.phtml');

//$ModelInterface = new \Zend\View\Model\ModelInterface();
//$ModelInterface->setTemplate('layout.phtml');

// this is the only class that has the setRoot() declared
//$ZendViewHelperViewModel = new \Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel();
//$ZendViewHelperViewModel->setRoot($ModelInterface); 

$renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$renderer->setResolver($resolver); 

//$renderer->layout('layout.phtml');
$renderer->headTitle('Zend');
$renderer->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$renderer->headLink()->setStylesheet('/test1.css');
$renderer->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/test2.css');
$renderer->headScript()->setFile('/javascript1.js');
$renderer->headScript()->appendFile('/javascript2.js');

$viewModel->setVariable('date', gmdate('r'));

echo $renderer->render($viewModel);
//echo $renderer->render($ZendViewHelperViewModel);
```

### Here's the `layout.phtml` code:

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> 
        <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headLink() . "\n" ?>
        <?php echo $this->headscript(). "\n"?>
     </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav">
            <?php echo $this->layout()->nav ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## What I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException'
>   with message '**Zend\View\Helper\Layout::getRoot: no view model
>   currently registered as root in renderer**' in
>   Zend/View/Helper/Layout.php:64 Stack trace:
>
> 0 Zend/View/Helper/Layout.php(37): Zend\View\Helper\Layout->getRoot()
>
> 1 [internal function]: Zend\View\Helper\Layout->__invoke()
>
> 2 Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(399): call_user_func_array(Object(Zend\View\Helper\Layout), Array)
>
> 3 views/layout.phtml(16): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('layout', Array)
>
> 4 views/layout.phtml(16): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->layout()
>
> 5 Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(506): include('...')
>
> 6 zendviewtest.php(32): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> 7 {main}   thrown in Zend/View/Helper/Layout.php on line 64

I believe this is because of the `$this->layout()` reference. When I remove that part, it starts working normally.

But I think the `$this->layout()` is necessary, because it's the natural way of passing the page content. If I remove it and use the plain `setVariable('content', ...)` it will break the Zend conventions, right?

I'd also like to use some nested layouts like header, footer etc. but I'm not sure how to implement that. I tried searching by the keywords and the error codes, but I can't find anything helpful. Please advise.

**UPDATE** What would be the best way to handle and display the page contents? Since I can't use the `echo $this->layout()->content` part suggested in the documentation, what should I replace it with?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->layout()` returns the `layout view model` witch you don't have.
to render other view scripts inside another one use `partial view helper`.

```
print $this->partial('path/to/other/view/script',array('param1'=>'param1'));
```

layout in zend framework is defined in the view_manager's configs and handled by the controller, since you are doing these steps manually u don't need a layout... just set your variables like `$viewModel->setVariable('param1', 'param1Value');` and use it in the view like `$this->param1` ...

> But I think the $this->layout() is necessary, because it's the natural
>   way of passing the page content. If I remove it and use the plain
>   setVariable('content', ...) it will break the Zend conventions, right?

you are absolutely WRONG, my application is completly based on zend mvc and i never have used `$this->layout()`, as i said `$this->layout()` returns the `layout view model` witch created by the view manager from the layout.phtml file , the view script that you currently have is the layout. setVariable('content', ...) is the only way you can proceed and there is no other way to do it ...

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. What would be the best way to handle the page content then? Since I can't use the echo `$this->layout()->content` part suggested in the documentation, what should I replace it with?

Comment: where and how you setting the `content` variable for the view?